# In $S_7$, describe the conjugates of $(1 2)(3 4 5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> In $S_7$, describe the conjugates of $(1 2)(3 4 5)$

**What I have done**

I'm not quite sure what the textbook refers to by "describe", in any case, I calculated (?) how many of them there are. it is right? If not, what should I actually do?

Let $\sigma=(1 2)(3 4 5)$ and $\tau$ any permutatión in $S_7$, then $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}$ has the same cycle structure of $\sigma$. Since $\tau \sigma \tau^{-1}= (\tau(1) \tau(2))(\tau(3) \tau(4) \tau(5)) $, for $\tau(1)$ we have $7$ possibilities and $6$ possibilities for $\tau(2)$. Since $(\tau(1)\tau(2))=(\tau(2)\tau(1))$, we have $(6\cdot7)/2=21$ $2$-cycles. Similarly, we have $(5\cdot 4\cdot 3)/3=20$ $3$-cycles. So in total, there are $21\cdot 20=420$ conjugates of  $(1 2)(3 4 5)$.

Comment: What you have done is correct

Comment: I suspect that the intention behind "describe" amounts to the first sentence of your solution. In slightly less technical terms, a conjugate of $\sigma$ is any permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ that maps two elements to themselves, maps two other elements to each other, and permutes the remaining three elements cyclically.